# display dialog of another activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

From activity 1, I open activity 2. Now when I am in the screen of activivty 2, I receive an event of activity 1 and onrecieve of that event i want to display a dialog. How can I do that?? 
While I am in activity 2 I dont see the dialog, but when I get back to activity 1, i see the dialog.

I want to see the dialog even when i am in screen of activity 2.
I looked into this link as well, but wasnt much helpful
[Showing dialog on top of another running activity (Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031951/showing-dialog-on-top-of-another-running-activity-android)
on receiving the reqd event, i call this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create separate dialog in Activity 2 and do below mentioned

1. Try to send broadcast when data related to activity 1 is received.
2. Create a Receiver class which will listen the broadcast
3. Now you have to use of Observer Design pattern i.e. when ever there is some event in Receiver class it will inform Activity B that data is arrived and show the appropriate dialog.

Please share the result if it not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

in your first activity (splashScreen ) write this function to create alert box

```
public static void MyAlertBox(String title, String mymessage,  Context context)
{
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
   .setMessage(mymessage)
   .setTitle(title)
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        .
        }
    })
   .show();
}
```

Declare  global veriable :

```
public static Activity currentActivity= null;
```

in Every activity :
 onResume() write "currentActivity=this ;"

Where you want to  display alert just write :(activity 1)

```
SplashScreen.MyAlertBox("Alert",
            "Alert box from activity 1",currentActivity );
```

hope it will work for you !!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, create a class, let's say a singleton, like this:

```
Class DialogDisplayer () {
    singleton implementation...

    weakReference context: Context

    fun showDialog(whatever data if needed) {
        dialogBuilder implementation ... 
        which uses the context from above, the rest you have
    }
}
on onResume() of each activity use DialogDisplayer.context = this
```

and finally, show the dialog from using class, in your first activity

```
like this: DialogDisplayer.showDialog(whatever data if needed)
```

This way the class will always show the dialog with context of the current active activity. I didn't write all the correct syntax, just the idea. WeakReference to allow this class to be GC collected. Maybe there are better ideas but this should work.